# Inputs are moved down by 1px

Tags: css

I am trying to make my buttons look properly when applied to `<a>` or `<input>` (at least in chrome). However the input is moved down by 1px but I really dont know why.

I tried to overwrite every style that comes from browser but it did not work.

I know I could just move it up with position relative or something else but thats not solution I am searching for, i want to know where that 1px comes from.

HTML:

```
<a class="button" href="#">link button</a>
<input class="button" value="input button" type="button" />
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 24px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: .3em .6em;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/wfmarc/pen/uHhvJ

Comment: If your question requires you to show your code (and almost all coding questions *do*), please include your code in your question, don't just post a demo and expect us to go there to see what you're doing. This time, I've done it for you; please, in future, do this yourself.

Comment: yeah thanks will do that next time

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to your button style.

Comment: +1 for quick response.....explanation was missing though, that was required too as per the user2030592!! :)

Comment: yeah  thanks that was the solution! however i dont understand where this comes from. i've added display: inline-block to and cant see something for vertical align in the inspector, but the input needs it and the link doesnt..

Comment: Thank you! This just saved me from a headache - I had a div, input field and select in one row and they were all in different heights... totally didn't realise it could be solved by this.

Answer (score 6):

**to explain** : `<a>` is by default an `inline` marker, so when you give them a display `block` or `inline-display`, you need to give them an alignment too for positioning....
add `vertical-align: top;` to your button class as per **sbeliv01** to give it a position element! :)